# Switch multiple toggle buttons on/off based on created() data

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have multiple toggle buttons , each which should be selected if that value is present in the obtained response which i get through created().

```
          <li>
              <input
                v-on:click="toggleCheckbox($event)"
                type="checkbox"
                v-model="selectedCategories.jfif"
                :checked="selectedCategories.jfif === 'active'" />
         </li>,
          <li>
              <input
                v-on:click="toggleCheckbox($event)"
                type="checkbox"
                v-model="selectedCategories.exif"
                :checked="selectedCategories.exif === 'active'" />
         </li>,
          <li>
              <input
                v-on:click="toggleCheckbox($event)"
                type="checkbox"
                v-model="selectedCategories.iptc"
                :checked="selectedCategories.iptc === 'active'" />
         </li>
```

I have multiple lists wrapped inside a ul.
The script is as shown:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedCategories: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleCheckbox(event) {
      console.log("Event is,", event, event.value);
    },
  },
  created() {
      //this is how i get the response
      this.selectedCategories = {"exif":"active","iptc":"active"}
    });
```

The issue is, if i get the data as :{"exif":"active","iptc":"active"} in this case jfif is not present. All the toggle switches are turned off. Even the one having "exif" and "iptc" get turned off. Where is my binding going wrong?

Comment: These are not checkboxes, they are just plain text fields? You should add type="checkbox" to your inputs. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @TomTruyen I have added them in my code, but had removed them here because the code was too much. I have now updated the code. The issue exists even with type="checkbox"  as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a dictionary , i used a list to bind and gave a value parameter to each li.

```
          <li>
              <input
                v-on:click="toggleCheckbox($event)"
                type="checkbox"
                value="exif"
                v-model="checkedCategories"
         </li>
          <li>
              <input
                v-on:click="toggleCheckbox($event)"
                type="checkbox"
                value="jfif"
                v-model="checkedCategories"
         </li>
          <li>
              <input
                v-on:click="toggleCheckbox($event)"
                type="checkbox"
                value="iptc"
                v-model="checkedCategories"
         </li>
```

Now i get the response in the format of ["exif","iptc"]

```
data(){
    return checkedCategories: []
    },
  created() {
      this.checkedCategories = ["exif","iptc"]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `v-model` together with `checked` doesn't make much sense since `v-model` sets `checked` itself. Read the Vue documentation on checkboxes: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox-1

Instead of `checked` you need to use the `true-value` and `false-value` attributes, so in your case `true-value="active"` and depending what you want to use, for example, `false-value=""` for an empty string, or `:false-value="null"` for `null` (notice the `:` or you'll get a string `"null"` instead).

Here is an working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kgewf04d/1/

Comment: I added true-value:"active" and false-value:"disabled", but now all are enabled. All exif, iptc and jfif are enabled. I only want exif and iptc but..!

Comment: Are you using `:` instead of `=`, or is it a typo?